# iOS Putting Shadow on UIView from Photoshop

Tags: ios, objective-c, shadow

I am trying to implement a UIView I was given by a designer in Photoshop.  I am having trouble with the shadow.  Here are the values from the "Outer Glow" in  Photoshop:

[image: Sample Outer Glow]

I have the shadow displaying with the following code:

```
myView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
myView.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0;
myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
```

I got the opacity and radius from the Photoshop values.  My question is, what does the "Quality" box (specifically the Range parameter, which is set at 50%), have to do with the shadow?  And is there a way for me to adjust that value in Xcode?

Thanks!

Comment: That shadow isn't black either `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.231f green:0.243f blue:0.29f alpha:1.0f]`

Comment: @Evan, thanks.  Is there a way to actually get those values listed in photoshop?  Or do you just grab the color of the little box inside the "Structure" section.

Comment: I've been using http://giantcomet.com/hues with this plugin http://bjango.com/mac/skalacolor/ but you can use the new beta for hues which has that functionality in it. http://giantcomet.com/hues/beta/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in the Quality box, including the “range” one, look like the defaults for Photoshop—you can probably safely ignore them here. If it turns out the look isn’t quite right, then no, there isn’t a way to adjust the way Core Animation renders the shadow; you may have to get the designer to give you an image asset for the shadow, which you can then place behind the view you want to cast a shadow.

Incidentally, the “size” parameter in PS is a radius, not a diameter, so your `shadowRadius` should be set to 40 to match the settings above.